# How to remove data from Firebase after every 24 hours?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an Ionic application with Firebase Database support. One of my feature of application is polling/voting. I want to refresh my object(i.e make empty to the data) after every 24 hours. I want to achieve this without writing any code to the client side, is it possible that firebase can maintain this routine by it self? Here is the snap, I want to refresh **polls** object after every 24 hours [image]

Comment: See the sample of periodically deleting unused accounts with Cloud Functions for Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#other_examples_of_batch_jobs_in_the_firebase_cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little search I found [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/), it can be very easy to operate what you need.

However, I think you should keep your data in the db and change your query to pull data by date.

Also you can use cron-job in any serverside program, to clean the firebase data.